# How to limit the number of Related Posts?

Tags: get-template-part

In my theme's file single.php, there is this part of code to get Related Videos:

```
      <?php
      if ( $wp_query ->have_posts() ) {

        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
          get_template_part( 'preview', get_post_format() );
        endwhile;

      }

      wp_reset_postdata(); 
    ?>
```

But this get the entire loop of all posts on the website.
I'm wondering, is there a way to limit this and display for example 10 posts?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the argument **post_per_page**
 to limit the posts.

Before your loop it should be something like this.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => 'custom_post',
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 


// your loop 
if ( $wp_query ->have_posts() ) {

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
      get_template_part( 'preview', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;

}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

If it is the custom post, make sure to replace **custom_post**

Comment: I should only replace `custom_post` to `post`, and now its working like a charm!
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Here, If it's a default wordpress **post**, it's not necessary to add **'post_type' => 'post'**.